# how to show the sqlite data in uitableview on otherviewcontroller?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sqlite, uitableview

i have viewcontroller .h .m and .xib that contain registration form to insert update and delete.

and i have other xib that contain uitableview that show the sqlite data .how can i display ???

i write the code but its gives the error on array of viewcontroller page and other control that are used in viewcontroller.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return  1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [data count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"salary"];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    name.text = [[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];
    salary.text = [[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"salary"];
}
```

here data is `NSArray` in `viewcontroller.h` file gives error here

and also in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method `name.text` and `salary.text` gives error because it is the textfield of viewcontroller.

how can i solved it ?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure the data array should be available in otherViewController. For that create a array property in .h file of OtherViewController and while loading this view controller, assign the data array to this property.

Well as you are using SQlite database, you can fetch the data from the database(you'll need to add additional code) in OtherViewController and display it the tableView there.

Also you can't access the private variables of a view controller inside a different view controller. You will have to create properties for them or create public methods.

Comment: hello 
thanx for reply me ...


i want to ask that i create the uitable programatically in  viewcontroller. And otherviewController have registration form .when i click on submit button of otherviewcontroller , its shows the sqlite data in tableview of viewcontroller..... 

it is possible to do .... because registration form on Otherviewcontroller and tableview is on Viewcontroller...

plz its very imp......

Comment: In -viewWillAppear of viewController which has the tableView, reload the data from the database and reload the tableView. To reload the tableView use `[tableView reloadData]`. Call this only after you have refreshed your tableview's data source.

Answer (score 0):

do it like this.. First create temporary dictionary and than fetch the data from that..

```
NSDictionary * tmpDictn = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [tmpDictn valueForKey:@"name"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [tmpDictn valueForKey:@"salary"];
```

And same here..

```
NSDictionary * tmpDictn = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
name.text = [tmpDictn valueForKey:@"name"];
salary.text = [tmpDictn valueForKey:@"salary"];
```